# Alias doesn't seem to read from STDIN

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, alias

I'm looking for an alias to convert hex from `hexdump` output into "Python's" hex notation:

```
$ echo "5f 74 34 0c c9 7b 9f f8  7a 7c 46 ff ff 5c 31 26" | sed 's/  */\\x/g' | awk '{print "\\x"$0}'
\x5f\x74\x34\x0c\xc9\x7b\x9f\xf8\x7a\x7c\x46\xff\xff\x5c\x31\x26
```

The above works so I tried creating an alias in my `.bashrc` as such:

```
alias pythonhex="sed 's/  */\\x/g' | awk '{print \"\\\\x\"$0}'"
```

But it doesn't seem to work:

```
$ echo "5f 74 34 0c c9 7b 9f f8  7a 7c 46 ff ff 5c 31 26" | pythonhex 
\x
```

It appears in this case that `sed` isn't getting anything from STDIN, and `awk` is just prepending `\x` to nothing.

Comment: I think the problem is you're using double quotes as the outer quotes, which means that $0 is getting interpreted at the time the alias is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a quoting issue. Use single quotes to prevent `$0` from expansion, and properly escape each literal single quote:

```
alias pythonhex='sed '\''s/  */\\x/g'\'' | awk '\''{print "\\x"$0}'\'
```

Comment: You are correct, quoting is a real problem with the alias command interface. The problem is that you need to pass the shell parser with the alias definition. UNOS (the first UNIX clone) had a method to bypass the parser for alias definitions that thus could be entered in raw form. I recently decided to add this trick to the Bourne Shell. If you are interested, have a look into the Bourne Shell man page and check the section for #-commands: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/bosh.1.html

Answer (score 1):

It is true that your alias problem was a quoting issue, resolved correctly by the user [choroba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13792/choroba).

But you may consider a simpler function:

```
pythonhex(){ printf "\134x%s" "$@"; echo; }
```

Used as:

```
$ pythonhex 5f 74 34 0c c9 7b 9f f8  7a 7c 46 ff ff 5c 31 26
\x5f\x74\x34\x0c\xc9\x7b\x9f\xf8\x7a\x7c\x46\xff\xff\x5c\x31\x26
```